# A $n$ variables inequality with sine function

Tags: inequality, contest-math, lagrange-multiplier

For $a_i>0(i=1,2,3\dots ,n)$ , Prove:
$$
\frac {(a_1+a_2)(a_2+a_3) \dots (a_{n-1}+a_n)(a_1+a_2+a_3+\dots+a_n)}{a_1 a_2 \dots a_n} \ge \left(\frac{\sin{\frac{2\pi}{n+2}}}{\sin{\frac{\pi}{n+2}}}\right)^{n+2}
$$

This problem was proposed by Nairi Sedrakyan in IOM (International Olympiad of Metropolises) shortlist 2020, it’s problem A2.

(Fan inequality) For $b_i \in \mathbb{R}\quad(i=1,2,3\dots,n)$ and $\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^n b_i=0$ ,we have
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n b_ib_{i+1} \le \cos{\frac{2\pi}{n}}\sum_{i=1}^n b_i^2
$$

With sine function involved, the first thing I thought was that this was a Fan-Type inequality. For this type, the general method is to use AM-GM or Cauchy inequality with undetermined coefficients to "generate" sine or cosine functions, but it is hard to use either method on LHS.

Another thought is to prove this problem with Lagrange Multiplier Method which can solve Fan inequality. For $n$ variable case, it is hard to solve $n$ equations, so I tried LMM when $n=3$(because $n=2$ is trivial). For this case, the equations can be
$$
a_1+a_2+a_3=0\\
a_1a_2a_3=0
$$
which is impossible because of $a_i>0(i=1,2,3\dots ,n)$.

Is there any solution or idea to solve this? Help me, please.

Comment: This reminds me of https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3259944/42969, I wonder if there is a connection.

Comment: if it's an olympiad problem, can you not find its solution published somewhere?

Comment: No, dear dezdichado, this problem is from the shortlist of IOM, which is not meant to be published. I hear this problem from a friend who claimed to attend the shortlist. As his word, it can be solved by geometry method which perplexs me a lot.

Comment: in that case, I am more inclined to believe that this can be transformed into the problem mentioned in the above comment, which is solved by Ptolemey here:
https://mathoverflow.net/questions/332726/how-to-prove-this-inequality-of-karamata-typeby Ptolemey's theorem!